# how to get the height and width of an image in C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I am trying to get the height and width of an image from websites but it always return 0, as the image is not yet downloaded so i used the following code and still didnt work as the image will start downloading only after the method end, so it hang

```
 someMethod
   {      
    foreach(string imagepath in paths){
    IsDownloaded = false;
    image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagepath));
    image.ImageOpened += image_ImageOpened;
    while (!IsDownloaded) ;
    /// code that will use image.PixelHeight only if it satisfy a condition then break
   }

    private void image_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsDownloaded = true;
    }
```

Does anyone have any alternative or any fix for this supported in metro style apps

Comment: There is a way how to get file info information. Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx

Comment: just a warning, if for any reason any of the images fails to download your code will spin indefinitely at `while (!IsDownloaded)`. much better to put your code in the `ImageOpened` handler, which will only fire when an image has been downloaded and decoded successfully

Answer (score 4):

You can't use asynchronous programming like that - remove this line:

```
while (!IsDownloaded) ;
```

And put everything after it inside the `image_ImageOpened` method.
We usually refer to this as 'chaining', when you have a bunch of asynchronous methods, you have to continue processing after the completion of each one.

An example from my own code of getting width/height:

```
        BitmapImage imageSource = new BitmapImage();
        private void getImage()
        {
            Uri uir= new Uri("PATH", UriKind.Absolute);
            imageSource.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>(imageopenened);
        }

        void imageopened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HEIGHT = ImageSource.PixelHeight;
            WIDTH = ImageSource.PixelWidth;
        ...
        }
```

Comment: if i used the event handler, how can i pass parameters to it? because ill need to change some properties that exist in the orginial method

Comment: @EsoHasInsomnia what do you need to change? The EventArgs object may contain what you need, otherwise you can make certain objects members of the class if they need to be changed by different methods

Comment: I have an array of strings that i must access that was evaluated before the loop, and i have another string that i must modify that i have its reference passed to the method that i am in it